# issue when scraping website using curl php

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to get all hotels names for city Al Riyad from website TripAdvisor this is my code:

```
require_once(APPPATH."../simple_html_dom.php");

      $postfields = array(
          "sl_opp_json" => "%7B%22HOTELS_AB_SLOT_0%22%3A%22eb6ce073-5ea4-4182-ab18-9d656fe9bbc5%22%2C%22HOTELS_SLOT_0%22%3A%225c1f95f2-50aa-4c1b-89ea-f957ea5607fd%22%7D",
          "plSeed" => "845179989",
          "showSnippets" =>"false",
          "offset" =>"120",
          "reqNum" =>"2",
          "changeSet" =>"",
          "puid" =>"WtT-4QoQJX8AAmsw3QgAAABC"
      );
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Hotels-g293995-Riyadh_Riyadh_Province-Hotels.html");
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($postfields));
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $response;
```

but the result of $response give me this message :

> "Votre requête n'est pas valide. Merci d'envoyer une requête HTTP
>   valide."
>
> "Your request is invalid Please send a valid HTTP request."

Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do they have an API? they probably dont like scrapers.

Comment: sorry smith io dont now if they have an API or no

Comment: hint, they do.. And rules about not scraping,.

Comment: lel, just do a normal GET request, and you get all the hotels. also, your last post parameter looks like a CSRF token, and CSRF tokens are tied to specific cookie sessions id, and you don't hardcode any cookie session id here. also, get rid of simple_html_dom, it's plain out obsolete, has been for a long time, better tools are built-in to PHP, use DOMDocument/DOMXPath instead.

Comment: Added message in English for better understanding of issue, Fixed common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to condone whatever you're doing as it seems to be against their policies - find their API here: https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/description/

That being said, if you're open to some extra parsing... you can try the below as a starting point (HINT: use get to return the page as is and manually write rules to parse it)

```
    <?php

        $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Hotels-g293995-Riyadh_Riyadh_Province-Hotels.html");
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_GET,1);
          //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($postfields));
          $response = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          echo "<pre><!--";//remove this(and below) and do whatever you want with the result page
          var_dump($response);
          echo "--></pre>";
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for all i geted the data from another website using my first code